# Generics inside the function parameters in Kinect app

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect, kinect-sdk

i was reading about Kinect and i found this code :

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace Kinect.Toolbox {

 public abstract class Notifier: INotifyPropertyChanged {

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  protected void RaisePropertyChanged < T > (Expression < Func < T >> propertyExpression) {

        var memberExpression = propertyExpression.Body as MemberExpression;

        if (memberExpression == null)
            return;

        string propertyName = memberExpression.Member.Name;

        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
 }
}
```

i was able to understand a little bit but i want to know how the Generics work in here:

`protected void RaisePropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpression)`

Comment: Basically it's extracting the name of a property from an expression like `x => x.SomeProperty` so it can use it when calling the `PropertyChanged` event.

Comment: @ thank you @juharr  i hope you provide a full explanation or documentation pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Linq Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions?view=netframework-4.7.1) is something to look at.

> Provides the base class from which the classes that represent expression tree nodes are derived.

[This is a good resource for combining the generics with expression, it goes through an example](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-expression)

It's an argument of type delegate(which 'Func' is. It could also use 'Action' or 'Predicate' because they are a type of delegate) and Func< T > means your delegate will return a type of T.